# Couldn't find driver exception when running php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, migration, database-migration

I found a problem in my code like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'sistem-inventory' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException
```

I have already tried uncommenting these 2 lines in my php.ini but the error is still the same.

```
extension=pdo
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: After you edited your php.ini did you restart PHP? For example, on a Mac run `brew services restart php`

Comment: how can i restart it on windows?

Comment: Do you know which http server you are using? For example, Apache or IIS.
For Apache you can use `apachectl graceful`. If you are using IIS you'll have to search for the command you need ;)

Comment: i use Apache but i'll make sure to do it, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

PHP on Windows uses DLL files instead of so files. To enable this driver you'll need to use the following extension lines in your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

These DLLs should exist in the system's extension_dir. They should be included with the Windows versions of PHP you have but if they weren't, you can get them from the appropriate PHP zip distribution at https://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply, but i already tried adding ````extension=php_mysqli.dll````, ````extension=php_pdo.dll````, and  ````extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll```` in my php.ini but still couldnt fix anything